# Grep, no value return

Tags: directory, search, grep

I am searching for a word, in this case "hehe" that is located in the file findTest

by using grep, but when i initiate the search:

```
grep -r "hehe"
```

or

```
grep -lr "hehe"
```

it starts but after 5 min waiting nothing happens, even if i am in the same directory as the file.
the only way i get a results straight away is being in the same directory and typing:

```
grep "hehe" findTest
```

Are their any other ways to search for a word? even if not in the same directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `grep` command expects either a file (or, in the case of `-r`, directory) name or input from the standard input stream - it's just sitting waiting for you so supply one or the other.

As an alternative to typing the name of the current directory, you can use the shorthand `.` or `./` i.e.

```
grep -r "hehe" .
```

or

```
grep -r "hehe" ./
```

Comment: I can see when it searches it finds its path and the word, but when does it stop the search? has been like this for a couple of minuts

Comment: @DanielS. If you are having a problem, post the command you ran. If you ran something such as `grep -r foo /large-disk-with-a-lot-of-data/*` it is going to take a while.

Comment: hehe yeah that might be the case thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0):

Also you can grep into a file with these code that have the same output

```
grep -i "statement" file.ext
cat file.ext | grep statement
```

Comment: i get the samme response, No such file or directory

Comment: Hey man! you have to replace "file.ext" with your file!

Comment: hehe that i know, i have done it :)